# Why do dual N-back games use certain letters?

Tags: intelligence, memory

Every implementation of [dual n-back](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-back) that I've ever seen uses the set of letters 'C', 'H', 'K', 'L', 'Q', 'S', 'R' and 'T'.

Why is that?

Comment: Interesting. Might be to reduce ambiguity, those letters are mostly visually and audibly distinct as opposed to making a test of C D B G P or O G C Q D

Comment: I don't know that it *always* has to use those letters. (see www.brainboffin.com; also, a quick lit search shows it's also been done with numbers and Mandarin phonemes). I suspect it's partly to do with the phonetic properties of the sounds, as Ben Brocka suggests, and partly because the dual n-back has mostly been run by a single lab (Jaeggi). It's easier for them to consistently use the same experimental setup, and increases their chances of reproducing the effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The set is not always the one you suggest. There are many implementations that don't even involve letters, but use random shapes, numbers, spatial locations, or other stimuli.

In [Jaeggi et al., 2007](http://www.psy.unibe.ch/unibe/philhuman/psy/apn/content/e5616/e5621/e6314/e6333/files6334/Jaeggi_et_al2007_ger.pdf), they used spatial locations for the visual task, and

> The auditory material consisted of eight German consonants (c, g, h, k, p, q, t, and w) spoken in a female voice and **selected on the basis of their distinctiveness**.

(emphasis mine).

In [Takeuchi et al. 2010](http://www.jneurosci.org/content/30/9/3297.short), they used numbers and locations:

> “Dual” N-back task. In this task, the number stimuli consisted of numbers, 1 to 4, presented in a random sequence in one of four places on a line.